# Discord.net bot not sending files with SocketTextChannel.SendFileAsync()

Tags: c#, .net-core, bots, .net-5, discord.net

I'm developing a bot for my discord server. One of the bot' functions - approve the player's proposal (message format "Text + attached file"), by copying this message into a special channel. I couldn't find a way to send a file using the `SendMessageAsync` function, so I use `SendFileAsync`, like that:

```
        [Command("approve")]
        public async Task Approve([Remainder] ulong id)
        {
            var sourceMsg = await Context.Channel.GetMessageAsync(id);
            if (sourceMsg == null)
                return;
            await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"Approving offer at {id}");
            var targetChannel = Context.Guild.TextChannels.Single(x => x.Name == _config["approved"]);

            if (sourceMsg.Attachments.Count > 0)
            {
                var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                var file = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(sourceMsg.Attachments.ElementAt(0).Url);
                using (System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(file))
                {
                    var fileAtt = new FileAttachment(stream, sourceMsg.Attachments.ElementAt(0).Filename);
                    await targetChannel.SendFileAsync(fileAtt, sourceMsg.Content);
                }

                return;
            }
            await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Can not approve offer without attached songfile");
        }
```

The problem is that when `SendFileAsync` is called, the bot hangs for some unknown reason without throwing any exceptions.

I looked for a solution on the Internet, but did not find anything comprehensible

I also thought that maybe the problem is that before sending the bot downloads the file using `HttpClient`, but if instead of the downloaded file I specified a local one, placed directly in the folder with the bot's executable, the same thing happened

I'm using Discord.Net v3.1.0, .NET Core 5.0

UPD: Bot still reacting on commands, but every new '!approve' command still freeze on `SendFileAsync`

UPD2: Ok, i fix that. The problem was a file weight, it was too big. By default, Discord users can send files weight not exceeding 8MB, but accidently all of my test files weight be a much more than 8MB, so discord blocks file sending, and, i dont know why, bot isn't crashes and not throws any exception. If you faced this problem too, just check file weigths

Comment: Generally async operation should be awaited and might need to Configure await so the context can either be captured or not captured. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait?view=net-5.0

Answer (score -1):

Change this line:

`await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"Approving offer at {id}");`

To:

`await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"Approving offer at {id}").ConfigureAwait(true);`

Do the same thing other async calls as well

Comment: i've tried this, but nothing was changed and bot still freezing when `SendFileAsync` called, and the most thing that bot doesnt crashes and still reacting on other commands

Comment: Not sure why it was downvoted.